# Setting image Uri in GridView

Tags: android, gridview, uri, gallery, adapter

I'm trying to add an image from your phones gallery into a gridView using its uri.
Unfortunately it doesn't do anything and I can't seem to find a way to make it work.

My Adapter:

```
public class ImageGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


public Uri imageUri;


private Context mContext;

public ImageGridAdapter(Context c) {
    this.mContext = c;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {

    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return 0;
}


public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    imageUri = PictureGroupActivity.selectedImage;


    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageURI(null);
    imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);

    return imageView;
   }
}
```

The adpater should be taking the imageUri from onActivtyResult:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.picture_group_gridView);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Toast.makeText(PictureGroupActivity.this, "selectedImage ma hodnotu: " + selectedImage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }
}
```

I've set the gridView in my onCreate inside my activity as so:

```
GridView gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.picture_group_gridView);
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageGridAdapter(this));

    gridView.invalidateViews();

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(PictureGroupActivity.this, "You clicked " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

When choosing a photo from the gallery, the gridView remains empty. How do you I make it work? What am I doing wrong ? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class ImageGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


public Uri imageUri;


private Context mContext;

public ImageGridAdapter(Context c) {
    this.mContext = c;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return 5;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {

    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return 0;
}


public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    imageUri = PictureGroupActivity.selectedImage;


    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageURI(null);
    imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);

    return imageView;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, finally did something! :D It added the picture into the gridView (changed the 5 to 1) But when adding another picture it overwrites, how do you make it stay ?

Comment: change PictureGroupActivity.selectedImage to a ArrayList . Once you get a image, you store uri in it . and return size of list in getitemcount.

Answer (score 0):

If you always return 0 from `getCount()`, then your list will always be empty. Similarly, you need to return something from `getItem()` so that your View knows what data is associated with which list item. You might want to use a more concrete `Adapter` implementation like [`ArrayAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) that can handle some of this for you.

Comment: Fair enough, I returned 1 in getCount() , and now it displays it in the gridView, finally. I now want the image to stay there when I add another image, any help with that ?